# radio button in tableviewcell for each section - ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, radio-button

my tableview containing two sections , each section contains n numbe of rows, in which my 1st row of each section dont have radio button. i am finding difficulty to program a group of selected radio button.

[image]

in this example , "prison break" and "homeland" are my sections. this section contains 6 rows. only 4 rows are having radio button , i need to toggle between these two correspondingly.

i have tried with creating all radiobutton array in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and in add target for each button , i am deselecting all others.

```
-(IBAction)toggleButton:(UIButton *)button{
//select the tapped radio button.
button.selected = !button.selected;
// Unselect all others.
for (id key in _myButtonDict) {
    UIButton *btn = [_myButtonDict valueForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
    if ([_myButtonDict valueForKey:key] != button) {
        [[_myButtonDict valueForKey:key] setSelected:NO];
    }
} }
```

Comment: Did u find any solution? I want the same.

Comment: yes. i found solution by myself.

Comment: all you need to do is handle through sections and rows. section contains n number of answers and it wil b easier to do radio button programming as well. let me know of any questions. thanks.

Comment: Can you please add some code part on this @sanjayzed

Comment: @RamS i have posted answer. Pl let me know if u hav questions. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface RadioButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger *row;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger *section;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//create a tableviewcell
//add the radio button to each cell.
    RadioButton *radioButton = [RadioButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        //radiobutton properties.


 radioButton.tag      = indexPath.section;
    radioButton.row   = indexPath.row;
[radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    cell.accessoryView = radioButton;
return cell;
}
```